# Continuous data streaming from NFC to iPhone in Swift?

Tags: swift, iphone, nfc

I have an NFC tag that has integrated environmental sensors inside (MLX90129 to be exact). I would like to make an iPhone app that can read the realtime data from the tag multiple times per second and graph them. I'm not looking for background tag reading, and you can assume that the app will be open and the phone is near the tag at all times.

From what I can see on Apple documentation and other sources, the Swift support for NFC tags is mostly built for single session interrogation. Has anyone succeeded in getting continuous and repeated NFC tag reading for this type of purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out: "*to make continuous and repeated NFC readings*" it's not the intended functionality.

While I think that you can sort this out, there's another thing that could be a headache... **to make *multiple readings per second* it's directly confronted to the current implementation of NFC tag reading in iOS.**

Every time you start a reading, it shows the native window which informs the user that you are making a NFC Reading. A part of this process is the interaction of the user, and is exactly that part the one that imposes a time constraint. Even if the interaction with the user is not needed, there is an animation, and that animation has its lifecycle's events (start reading, reading, OK, KO, close...).

Afaik you can't bypass that animation which definitely could represent a couple seconds in the best case.

With that said, you should have a few things in mind, if you still want to try:

[NFCTagReaderSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/nfctagreadersession) can only have one active reading at a time, and when that reading ends (OK/KO), it should be invalidated. So if you want to make another reading, you'll need to create and configure a new instance.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful information, I didn't know that the animation could pose a timing constraint. I guess my next best option is to see how fast I can repeatedly create a session, invalidate it after reading, and create a new session? The UI will probably be a bit crazy with the prompt popping up over and over but this is for research so it doesn't matter too much.

Comment: Yes, if you are still up for it, that would be your next issue. In fact, there are a few problems associated with the creation of multiple tag sessions. Probably you will have to implement the management because it will be frequent to find errors like "Unavailable" while trying to create a new session.